# Eclipse, java, copy code

Tags: java, copy, filewriter

I apologize for the stupid question.
I encountered the following problem:
I must copy java-code from site to Eclipse, where each line began with it's number, for example:

```
49     try {
50              Object[] args = new Object[] { null, b, new Integer(0),
51                      new Integer(b.length) };
52              clazz = (Class) method.invoke(loader, args);
53          } finally {
54              method.setAccessible(false);
55          }
56          return clazz;
57     }
58
```

but Eclipse, of course, doesn't recognize this code.
And I'm tired of manually delete numbers. 
Does Anybody Know how to automate this process?;)

Comment: You're code makes absolutely so sense

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can simply copy and paste then use vertical selection (default: alt+shift+A) in eclipse

Comment: Didn't know this awesome feature before. Would certainly have saved me some wear and tear on my keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the find-replace feature.

Just do <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> on the editor, in the "find" input, write

```
^\d+(.*)$
```

And in the "replace" input field write

```
$1
```

Then check the "Regular expression" checkbox, and click "replace all"

Answer (score 0):

```
alt+shift+A
```

sortcut for part selection

Answer (score 0):

There's a multi-selection option (multiple lines).

It's an icon in the toolbar under the menu.

The Windows shortcut is <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>

[image]